SwatchLegend using a table
I am facing a problem while adding another column to the SwatchLegend using a table. The below code is provided in Mathematica Documentations
Original Code
table[pairs_] := 
     TableForm[pairs, 
      TableHeadings -> {{"Group A", "Group B", "Group C"}, {"color", 
         "mascot"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]

SwatchLegend[63, {"lion", "whale", "rocket"}, LegendLayout -> table]


Modified Code
table[pairs_] := 
 TableForm[pairs, 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"color", "mascot", "Symbol"}}, 
  TableAlignments -> Center]

SwatchLegend[63, {"lion", "whale", "rocket"}, LegendLayout -> table]


Code with error and no output
 SwatchLegend[63, {"lion", "whale", "rocket"}, {"A", "B", "C"}, LegendLayout -> table]

Code suggested by ChatGPT but with error
(*Define the new data including the additional column*)
pairs = {{"red", "lion", "A"}, {"blue", "whale", "B"}, {"green", 
    "rocket", "C"}};

(*Define the updated table form with the additional column*)

table[pairs_] := 
  TableForm[pairs, 
   TableHeadings -> {None, {"color", "mascot", "symbol"}}, 
   TableAlignments -> Center];

(*Create the updated SwatchLegend with the new layout*)
SwatchLegend[63, {"lion", "whale", "rocket"}, 
 LegendLayout -> table[pairs]]



How to make three columns for colors, mascots and symbols respectively
in the SwatchLegend environment modifying the above code.


pairs is a list of list that contain two items (i.e. pairs); the swatch and the label.  If you want to add an additional column then you must provide the values for that column. An easy means to do this is to pass the additional column values to the table function.
ClearAll[table]
table[pairs_, extra_] :=
 TableForm[Append @@@ Transpose[{pairs, extra}]
  , TableHeadings -> {{"Group A", "Group B", "Group C"}, {"color", "mascot", "symbol"}}
  , TableAlignments -> Center]

When calling table include the extra column's values
SwatchLegend[63, {"lion", "whale", "rocket"}
  , LegendLayout -> (table[#, {"L", "W", "R"}] &)]


Hope this helps.
